# Copy constructor with linked list only copying first node

Tags: c++, linked-list, copy-constructor

I am using a copy constructor for a linked list, but it is actually only copying the first node in the linked list. I am not sure what is causing this. Any ideas?

```
LinkedList::LinkedList(const LinkedList& source) {
    // Implement this function
    head = nullptr;
    tail = nullptr;
    Node* tempNode = source.head;

    while(tempNode != nullptr)  {
        insert(tempNode->loc, tempNode->yr, tempNode->mo, tempNode->temp);
        tempNode = tempNode->next;
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure the problem is in this copy constructor? Perhaps the problem lies in `tempNode->next` not properly pointing to the next element, or perhaps it lies within `LinkedList::insert`. Have you stepped through the example with a debugger?

Comment: I am currently trying to step through the entire thing. I am thinking it may actually lie in my insert function taking a second look at it

Comment: This is caused by possibly not having a linked list properly chained in `source` in the first place. Or perhaps `insert` is broken. There's nothing wrong with the code provided, assuming the code that built the linked list in `source` is sound and well tested, and `insert` is as well. As we have *neither* of those at our disposal, a *guess* is the best you can hope for right now.

Comment: ahh okay. Yeah I will retackle the insert section and get back to yall!

Comment: There is a widely spread StackOverflow superstition, that if you leave out any "surely correct, not involved" code, then the problem will be found, finally, inside that code you left out. Making a [mcve] usually is the good-luck charm against that.

Comment: @new_programmer_22 -- From looking at your code, I see nothing conceptually wrong with it.  It basically revealed a flaw in your `insert` function, if nothing else.

Comment: @Yunnosch: I love the way you put that! Of course the response is inevitably, "oh sorry I didn't know the problem was in that part" and we're like "well duh we know that .. that's why we have a MCVE requirement as a _rule_ so why can't you people just follow it agh agh agh agh agh"